# Why there is no connection to AWS RDS database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Even if **Public accessibility: Yes** I can not connect to RDS PostgreSQL.

EC2 can reach the internet without a problem but the database server can not be reached from  EC2 or from the internet.

- Both RDS and EC2 have sg-69ecb029 VPC security groups.
- I can not `telnet ...amazonaws.com 5432` from anywhere.
- All 3 subnets have an Internet gateway

## What is stopping the connection of RDS?

While adding database I used an IAM user and there was a warning about listing aliases:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::24445566661:user/h-manager is not authorized to perform: kms:ListAliases on resource: *
```

Even if I try to connect from EC2 which is in same  VPC `pg_isready`  returns `*.......ds.amazonaws.com:5432 - no response`

and
`pgAdmin` returns `ETIMEDOUT 52.***.***.**:5432`

[image: RDS]

---

[image: ROUTE TABLE]

Comment: So your ec2 instance has the security group `sg-69ecb029`? Is your RDS in a public subnet with a route table containing an internet gateway? Can your EC2 speak outside to the internet?

Comment: Also can you connect via the hostname not the public ip address?

Comment: Check security group of DB inbound and outbound group of EC2? also heck DB is in public subnet

Comment: thank you for your answers, I have updated my question. I have deleted database and launched it again but still I can not create a public RDS server.

Comment: Check specifically the inbound rules on the two security groups on that instance and see if traffic is allowed on port 5432

Comment: I'd recommend carefully reading [Scenarios for Accessing a DB Instance in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html). Also, you mentioned that "All 3 subnets have an Internet gateway". Subnets can't have internet gateways. IGW is a VPC-level construct, not subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments.

Problem was about **VPC security groups**

#### The solution was to delete one of the security groups:

I have deleted one of the Security groups: `launch-wizard-1`  then modified the only remaining `sg-69ecb029`

I have added Inbound rules to `sg-69ecb029` and selected (launch-wizard-1) as a source.

#### Result:

`pg_isready` is returning
`..1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 - accepting connections`

@jarmod send a very useful [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html)